# Can I take chocolate and toffees into China, South Korea and Japan

Tags: food-and-drink

South Korea and Japan in March 2016 and I would like to know if I am able to take chocolate and toffees with me from England to eat while I am there.

Comment: For future readers remember that spreads like nutella are considered liquids so they might take it away from you. Oh yes, I once ate a 800g nutella jar in under an hour. You don't just throw nutella away. It is considered a sinful act in my religion.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**, you can.  I'm not aware of any country in the world that does not permit importing (commercially manufactured) chocolate and toffee.

That said, I'm not sure you need to, since high-quality chocolate is very easy to find in Japan and Korea, with wide selections available in any convenience store.  Sure, it's not going to be *exactly* the same as in the UK, but that's one of the joys of travel!

Comment: Indeed, products containing milk that has been processed to the degree as is the case for chocolate are usually not subject to any restrictions on dairy products. As for your second paragraph, at least in China, chocolate is almost non-existent (at least compared to the degree of chocolatification I'm used to from Germany), so it always makes for a nice gift for hosts.

Comment: A wide array of chocolate candy and other products are readily available in stores in Beijing and Taiyuan I can say.  Not in the smaller convenience stores but certainly in any of the many department stores.  Chinese-style bakeries might not use a lot, but plenty of western-style bakeries in those cities do.  Indeed chocolate makes a good gift for hosts in China but I always get it there.

Comment: With the exception of Kinder Eggs into America, but that's not because of the chocolate per se.